# The best way to create a TextView that looks like this

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, material-design

I'm trying to recreate this type of TextView. Is it Material Design TextInput or modified TextView?
How Can I put the line on top of TextView?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a `view` with background property. Use it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View line placed above the text view"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]